# json_normalize in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I am trying here to use json_normalize to somehow format the output of an API, but I keep getting a faulty and empty csv file. I tried to change `df2 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['LIST'])` , but keep getting this error message:

```
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Could you please guide me on what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot !

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://*hidden*Results/"

payload = json.dumps({
  "id": 12345
})
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic *hidden*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)


df1 = pd.DataFrame(response).iloc[:,:-2]
df2 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=None)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: I'm not expert with pandas. Just to understand, it works with `record_path=None` bot not when you pass `record_path=['LIST']`? [The documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) says that can receive `record_path: str or list of str, default None`, have you tried only with `'LIST'`?

Comment: Do you have the sample of the json file you are working with?

Comment: It is not working neither with record_path=['LIST'], neither with =None.
Unfortunately, cannot really share the json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the variable `response` in the call:

`df2 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=None)`

Which is an a `requests.models.Response` Object and you need to pass a `dict`, so you need to do something like `pd.json_normalize(response.json(), record_path=['LIST'])`

I tried it with this example and works:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [
...     {
...         "state": "Florida",
...         "shortname": "FL",
...         "info": {"governor": "Rick Scott"},
...         "counties": [
...             {"name": "Dade", "population": 12345},
...             {"name": "Broward", "population": 40000},
...             {"name": "Palm Beach", "population": 60000},
...         ],
...     },
...     {
...         "state": "Ohio",
...         "shortname": "OH",
...         "info": {"governor": "John Kasich"},
...         "counties": [
...             {"name": "Summit", "population": 1234},
...             {"name": "Cuyahoga", "population": 1337},
...         ],
...     },
... ]
>>> result = pd.json_normalize(data, ["counties"])
>>> result
         name  population
0        Dade       12345
1     Broward       40000
2  Palm Beach       60000
3      Summit        1234
4    Cuyahoga        1337
```

*EDIT* I will try to do this:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://*hidden*Results/"

payload = json.dumps({
  "id": 12345
})
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic *hidden*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

json_response = response.json()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(json_response).iloc[:,:-2]
df2 = pd.json_normalize(json_response, record_path=['LIST'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Hm.. seems like the same error message on line: result = pd.json_normalize(data, ["counties"])

TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: This example is adapted from the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) so you can try the one from the docs, but I have checked it again and it works fine for me. Are you sure this error is coming from the example I sent you?

Comment: Update: After running the below, I got the message:
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0]
//code//
df = pd.DataFrame(response)
df = pd.json_normalize(df)
print(df)

Comment: is the variable `response` a dictionary? because remember that `pd.DataFrame(...)` is waiting for a *dictionary* where the 3 dots are.

Comment: In order to get a dictionary from the response object do this: ```pd.DataFrame(response.json())```

Comment: Perhaps, If I put here a very short part of that exported file:

`0
b'{\n    "count": 412,\n    "name": "survey",\n    "columnNames": [\n        "Advanced Mode",\n        "Allow Anonymous",\n        "Allo'
b'w Multiple Submits",\n        "Assigned",\n        "Attribute",\n    ],\n    "rows": [\n        [\n            "1",\n            "1",\n            "Yes",\n            "unknown",\n       '`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243799/discussion-between-alexander-porcescu-and-anibal-jasin).